# Stationary points for $f(x,y)=4x^2-xy+4y^2+x^3y+xy^3-4$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Examine $f(x,y)=4x^2-xy+4y^2+x^3y+xy^3-4$ for extreme values
My attempt:
$$f_x=8x-y+3x^2y+y^3=0$$
$$f_y=-x+8y+x^3+3xy^2=0$$
Adding $f_x$ and $f_y$,I got $7x+7y+(x+y)^3=0$
$$(x+y)[7+(x+y)^2]=0$$
How do I get the stationary points from this?

The solution is given as $(0,0),(3/2,-3/2),(-3/2,3/2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of two real numbers is zero if and only if at least one of them is zero. Since $7+(x+y)^2>0$, the only solutions are given by $x+y=0$. Hence you must insert the condition $x+y=0$ into your equations $\partial f/\partial x=0$ and $\partial f/\partial y=0$.

[image]

Comment: I have posted the solution as given in the book

Comment: @PiGamma Edited, sorry. You need one more step.

Comment: Yeah ,I got the answer

Answer (score 1):

The equation you derived came from $f_x+f_y=0$.
On the other hand, notice that

\begin{align}
f_x-f_y
&=\left[(-x)^3+3(-x)^2y+3(-x)y^2+y^3\right]+9x-9y\\
&=(y-x)^3-9(y-x)
\end{align}

Let $u=x+y$ and $v=y-x$.
It follows that if $(x,y)$ is a stationary point the following system is satisfied:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
u^3+7u=0\\
v^3-9v=0
\end{array}
\right.$$

The first equation yields $u(u^2+7)=0$, so we must have $u=0$ since $u$ must be real.
The second yields $v(v^2-9)=0$, so we must have $v=0$ or $v=\pm3$.

Now it's a matter of recovering the pairs $(x,y)$ from the pairs $(u,v)$, and checking whether or not they are indeed stationary points.

$\qquad (1)$ $u=v=0:$ Corresponds to $x=y=0$, which is easily checked to satisfy $\nabla f=0$.

$\qquad (2)$ $u=0, v=3:$ Corresponds to $y=3/2$ and $x=-3/2$.

$\qquad (3)$ $u=0, v=-3:$ Corresponds to $y=-3/2$ and $x=3/2$.